# Which phrase is more preferable and correct: "value out of range" or "value is out of range"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

The question is: "Which phrase is more preferable and correct: *'value out of range'* or *'value is out of range'* " in context of technical documentation, specifications and technical description. 
I've encountered both of them, but for now I don't know which is more ideal and universal for all contexts.
Thanks

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: If you cannot delete your post yourself, there usually is a good reason for this. You cannot delete your own post as it has an upvoted answer, which would be lost. Deletion should happen with closed questions that have no value to future visitiors (does not apply here) or in exceptional cases, e.g., if you accidentally revealed private information or posted copyrighted content. See also [this Meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25088/255554).

Comment: If you don't want further downvotes you should edit the question to add some context.

Comment: I have regretted that I left my question here. I'm the question owner and I just want to delete it.

Comment: You cannot delete it because someone has taken the trouble to answer it and has gained upvotes for that answer. Also, "ownership" is moot: you have irrevocably licensed your content to Stack Exchange Inc (see Term 3 of the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal)). Vandalism of licensed content is not allowed.

Comment: My advice would be to ask the question of the people who are likely to see the message. They will be the true test case for you, and they're the ones you should have a vested interest in ensuring they understand what you mean. Also, sometimes *less is more* where these error messages are concerned. Try to keep it simple, with the option to gather more details about the error if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

*[Edit: removed my response to an error in the question, since corrected]*

Whether you use "is" or not is a question of style: error messages (which is what I assume this is) often use an abbreviated syntax that leaves out words like "is", so "Value out of range" is a normal error message. If you want to make it into a full sentence, you really need to add in the article (which again would be omitted in many error messages): "The value is out of range".

Comment: Thanks, Colin. And the last moment: Are intended phrases "equivalent" in more "extensive" sentences, like: "The error occurred. Column 'name' value out of range when fetching result rowset" ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, @RomanPerekhrest; but if you start with a full sentence with article "The error occurred", it would be odd not to continue with full sentences with articles.